# How do read-modify-write actions in c++11 achieve mutual visibility when executed by multiple cores?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I'm kind of confused about the mechanism behind read-modify-write action, for example, fetch_add. How do they avoid reading the old values and getting the result wrong when using relaxed memory order? here is the demo code:

```
std::atomic<int> global_counter = 0;

//thread 0
int counter0 = global_counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
assert(counter0 > 0);

//thread 1
int counter1 = global_counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
assert(counter1 > 0);
```

since both fetch_add actions are tagged with std::memory_order_relaxed, only their atomicity is garanteed. Is it possible that fetch_add actions in both threads read the old values of global_counter(which is 0), and then add on that old values? If it isn't, how do they achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. It is achieved by platform specific atomic instruction(s), e.g. using 'lock' prefix in x86 or 'll/sc' on others. The memory ordering controls the observed sequence of the modifications to *different* memory locations. It's a separate concern from atomicity.

Comment: Thank you, but there's one thing still confusing me. As far as I know,  atomic stores and loads without memory_order_seq_cst do not necessarily flush with the main memory(which may lead to loading old values).Does fetch_add flush in the latest value from memory before executed and flush the new value all the way down to memory after executed?

Comment: It's not really needed to "flush to main memory" up to until that value is actualy needed by another processor. Yes, atomic *loads* may read an "old" value (but not parts old, parts new value, that's the what "atomic" means in this context), but, on the other hand, atomic *read-modify-write* operations are required to read the last value written - "29.3 Order and consistency [#12]"